# Is it possible to check if certain layer is empty? CS6 Script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want function which checks if certain layer has all pixels with 0% transparency, in other words, layer is just empty.

```
function isLayerEmptyCheck(layer) {
   //code
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information in documentation ([Photoshop CS6 Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/scripting/Photoshop-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf), [Photoshop CS6 JavaScript Ref](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/scripting)) of any `artlayer` property of this kind.

Comment: So you need to check if the layer is empty or make a text layer? What's the point of creating of a text on a filled layer? Can’t you check layer bounds to see if it’s empty?

Comment: It is better idea, I checked it and it works. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only need to check of property of `artlayer` `bounds` to find out, if all values of its arrays are equal to `"0 px"`. When all of them are `"0 px"`, then it means that layer is empty.

Below I created function which checks if input layer is unfilled.

```
#target photoshop

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var certainLayer = doc.artLayers[0];

var isLayerEmpty = isLayerEmptyCheck(certainLayer);

alert(isLayerEmpty);

function isLayerEmptyCheck(layer) {

    var isLayerEmpty = new Boolean;

    var LayerBounds = layer.bounds;
    if (LayerBounds[0] === "0 px" && LayerBounds[1] === "0 px" && LayerBounds[2] === "0 px" && LayerBounds[3] === "0 px") {
        return isLayerEmpty = true;
    } else {
        return isLayerEmpty = false;
    }

}
```